# how to remove linking or seprate id value from this link

Tags: java, html

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=RULES&amp;id=35000000000000001648&amp;search=">Non-Banking Financial (Deposit Accepting or Holding) 
Companies Prudential Norms (Reserve Bank) Directions, 2007</a>
```

This is my HTML I want separated id  value and print it or I want to remove id value coz it 
varies    so  I   m not getting data or else how to remove link so that it doesn't depend on id. How can I do this?

Comment: Lacks description on where and how is this html generated. It was very ugly formatted, the question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

As i see your using aspx means your using ether c# or VB.net

This is how you can get the id value:
for C#:
Request.QueryString["id"]

for VB.net:
Request.QueryString("id")

Now if you want the link to be without an ID you have to remove it from your code, but if you remove the ID on what do you want to base your records?

Can you please give an example.

Comment: no actually i want to remove linking and i m using java technology i m getting html  <a target="_blank" href="http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=RULES&amp;id=35000000000000001648&amp;search=">Non-Banking Financial (Deposit Accepting or Holding) Companies Prudential Norms (Reserve Bank) Directions, 2007</a>  i have to print only Companies Prudential Norms (Reserve Bank) Directions, 2007

Comment: there shud be no linkng i m getting Companies Prudential Norms (Reserve Bank) Directions, 2007 but coming linking i want to remove this

Answer (score 0):

I did a test on your data:

Found this solution, first add this function:

```
public static String substringBetween(String str, String open, String close) {
if (str == null || open == null || close == null) {
    return null;
}
int start = str.indexOf(open);
if (start != -1) {
    int end = str.indexOf(close, start + open.length());
    if (end != -1) {
        return str.substring(start + open.length(), end);
    }
}
return "";}
```

Then wherever the string is getting written to the page:

```
String myString = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=RULES&amp;id=35000000000000001648&amp;search=\">Non-Banking Financial (Deposit Accepting or Holding) Companies Prudential Norms (Reserve Bank) Directions, 2007</a>";

        myString = substringBetween(myString, "\">", "</a>");
        System.out.println(myString);
```

The output was: **Non-Banking Financial (Deposit Accepting or Holding) Companies Prudential Norms (Reserve Bank) Directions, 2007**

So this should work please tell me if you need more help.